# CouchDB reduce function doesn't group emitted values correctly

Tags: couchdb

I'm a newbie to CouchDB, and was playing around with curl, but I can't seem to be able to reduce my data correctly

```
curl -X POST -d '{ 
  "map":"function(doc){ emit(doc.loc, 1) }",
  "reduce":"function(keys, values){ return sum(values) }"
}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:5984/users/_temp_view'
```

My intention is to reduce my docs based on their location (doc.loc) such as 'US', 'AU', 'CA'.

And I expect to get something like this:

```
{
  "rows":[
   {"key":"US", "value":10},
   {"key":"AU", "value": 5},
   {"key":"CA", "value": 10}
  ]
}
```

But instead I'm getting an empty key with a count of all docs

```
{"rows":[{"key":null,"value":1822}]}
```

Just as a sanity check I tried

```
emit(doc.loc, doc.loc)
```

and got

```
{"rows":[{"key":null,"value":"00AUAUAUAU...
```

Which means that my data does have a doc.loc on it

---

Again this is totally newbies level so I'm probably missing VERY simple.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem I was missing `?group=true` on my query.

```
curl -X POST -d '{ 
  "map":"function(doc){ emit(doc.loc, 1) }", 
  "reduce":"function(keys, values){ return sum(values) }" 
}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:5984/users/_temp_view?group=true'
```

gives me the result I expected

```
{"rows":[{"key":"--","value":25},{"key":"AU","value":493}, ...
```